# JMETER_.bat file is missing

Tags: jmeter

I just tried to install JMeter and I have downloaded the zip file from " download_jmeter.cgi". I have downloaded both file and unzip it, But in the bin, jmeter.bat is not showing to work on GUI mode.

I tried to learn from "https://www.guru99.com/guide-to-install-jmeter.html".

Please give an advise to work it.

Am very new to JMeter.

Comment: what's not working? what's your OS?

Comment: Win 10, Not able to open the Jmeter application

Comment: Java version is 8.

Comment: I installed it as per guru 99 but after do everythig Jmeter.bat is missing but guru99 showing to clkick it. Am bit confused

Comment: It's an old tutorial with old jmeter version, prefer to download from website

Comment: ok, Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure to install [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) or higher and to choose either 64-bit JDK or Server JRE
2. Make sure to download the **binary**, not the "source"

   [image: JMeter Download]

   Just in case you can use the following link in order to obtain latest [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)

   https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-4.0.zip
3. I would recommend running `jmeter.bat` not by double-clicking it, but using [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) or [Poweshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/getting-started-with-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6), this way you will be able to see if there are any errors. Here are Powershell commands to download, unpack and run JMeter

   - Download:

     ```
     Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-4.0.zip" -OutFile jmeter.zip
     ```
   - Unpack: `Expand-Archive -Path jmeter.zip`
   - Run: `cd jmeter\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\; ./jmeter.bat`

Answer (score 2):

Go to `bin` directory , `jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin` 
Run `jmeter` (windows batch file)
It will open GUI .

Answer (score -1):

If you have JMeter (Windows batch file) that's good to go. In some system, Jmeter bat file comes only in Jmeter ( it should have a sitting icon, and it should be a windows batch file)

Follow below youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Go92Nj_u7nw

Comment: If you have JMeter (Windows batch file) that's good to go. In some system, Jmeter bat file comes only in Jmeter ( it should have a sitting icon, and it should be a windows batch file)

Follow below youtube video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Go92Nj_u7nw

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).